# JBuilder : Import classes in project?

Tags: java, jbuilder

i have a package of classes compiled as jar file.

- how to import the package in JBuilder 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the JAR to the project [just as you would any other 3rd party JAR](http://www.borlandtalk.com/image-vp411062.html).